# Is the amount of pigment in one feature (e.g. hair, eyes, skin) connected to the amount of pigment in another?

Tags: human-biology, genetics, human-eye, hair, pigmentation

Let's say, genes allowing it, you have a red-haired child with hazel eyes. The hair is a darker/deeper orange color, so (if I recall correctly) having some degree of eumelanin—not much compared to phenomelanin but enough to darken it to that deeper red shade. Would the hazel eyes be connected to this trait, being a mix of pheomelanin with some eumelanin akin to the hair, or is eye color’s “pigment pool” entirely independent from hair color’s “pool?”

Also another perspective, if the head-hair and the facial hair (eyebrows, etc…) are that red color, does the body hair (arms, legs, etc) always have to match those and be reddish too, or is it more likely to be blonde/clear/etc?